# Get eigenvalues with Incremental PCA

Tags: python, scikit-learn, eigenvalue, dimensionality-reduction

I'm working with dimensionality reduction and would like to get eigenvalues ​​and eigenvectors from my dataset. Since there are several features (Images) I tried to use [Incrementa PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_incremental_pca.html), but I did not find a way to get the eigenvalues ​​/ eigenvectors in the documentation, is it possible to get them with the incremental PCA?

```
def get_incremental_pca(training,n_components,batch_size):

   ipca = PCA(n_components)
   return ipca.fit_transform(training) //The training set with reduced dimensionality
```

Comment: Please add a code that you tried here.

Comment: @MiheretabAlemu Ok

Comment: Did you get the answer? I faced the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's not much code to go off of here, so in general cases:

```
eigenvalues = ipca.explained_variance_ratio_

eigenvectors = ipca.components_

mu = ipca.mean_
```